# How to change HTML text with Javascript using event object

Tags: javascript, html

I can't understand why e.target.name is showing undefined even though e.target returns the node. How would I simply change the text using the event object?

```js
function changeText(e) {
  console.log(e.target, e.target.name);
  
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'fooBar':
      e.target.innerHTML = 'bar';
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p name="fooBar" onclick="changeText(event)">foo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `HTMLParagraphElement` does not have a `name` property. Also, the `name` attribute is **invalid** for `<p>` elements. Use `data-name="fooBar"` instead and access it using `event.target.dataset.name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeText(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('name'));
    switch (e.target.getAttribute('name')) {
    case 'fooBar':
        e.target.innerHTML = 'bar';
        break;
    }
}
```

e.target is a html node so you have to use DOM api to get attributes

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I'm still a little confused though why e.target.someAttribute seems to work fine in my webpage when it's attached to an img tag, but not when it's from a p tag. Very strange

Comment: depends what attribute you're talking about, for example `Id` and `className` would work , but `name` wouldn't.  think about `e.target` as a js class which has public `id` and `className` properties, but `name` for example is private, and to get it you should call instance method.